# Free Template Licence

Tags: html, templates

I'm a new web developer and I really want take care about what I can do and what I cannot do with open source template.

A local gym asked me to develop their web site and I found this template but I cannot understand what the licence allow me to do.

Licence web page: https://tympanus.net/codrops/licensing/

Can I just modify the strings and keep css, layout ecc as is it? Have I to 
change more contents?

Template: https://tympanus.net/codrops/2015/07/10/freebie-cardio-one-page-website-template/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's asking for legal advice.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking for an explanation of a license that is not included in the question.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing instead of directly about programming. **[See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/274963/1402846)** for details and the **[help]** for more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what they are saying is you can build a website and modify it to suit your needs. change content css html js as you want.

But do not try to sell their work or redistribute it.